# Fourier series- coefficients for specific function with listed conditions

Tags: fourier-series

There is a function $ f: \mathbb{R}\mathop{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R} $ which meets the conditions:

$ f(-x)=f(x) $ and $ f(x+ \pi)=-f(x) $ for $ x \in \mathbb {R} $

Show that the Fourier series coefficients are:

$a_{0}=a_{2}=a_{4}=a_{6}=...=0 $ and $b_{1}=b_{2}=b_{3}=b_{4}=...=0$

Comment: It would be helpful to know, how $a_k$ and $b_\ell$ are defined.

Comment: $a_{n}= \frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{+\pi}f(x)cos(nx)dx $ and

$b_{n}= \frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{+\pi}f(x)sin(nx)dx$